# How to select column from child table in linq

Tags: c#, sql, .net, linq, entity-framework

How do I include a 2nd level table column in my linq query?
I don't want .Net to perform lazy loading because there are other tables linked to these tables.

The table are

```
Quiz:    
 - Id
 - Name

Questions:    
 - Id
 - Name
 - quizId

Options:   
 - id
 - Name
 - QuestionId
```

Quiz and Questions have a one-to-many relationship. Questions to Option also have a one-to-many relationship.

```
var quiz=db.Quiz.include(a=>a.Questions)......ToList();
```

How can I include Options columns in my linq query?

Comment: are you using entity Frameork?

Comment: @Coder1409 See the tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to eargerly load grandchildren of an entity, the code below will achieve this, provided you have mapped the relationships correctly.

```
var quiz = db.Quiz
             .Include(a => a.Questions.Select(q => q.Options))
             .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Add to Questions property Options as ICollection and mapping as one to many.
Then You may use

```
var quiz=db.Quiz.include(a=>a.Questions).include(a=>a.Questions.Options).......ToList();
```

Or

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this won't work though cause it's multiple `Questions` and that multiple object won't have an `Options` property.  Each one in the collection will though

Comment: Indeed, but did the other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that you can just do multiple `Include()`s:

```
var quiz = db.Quiz
           .Include(x => x.Questions)
           .Include("Questions.Options")
           .ToList();
```

It's not completely strongly typed though like @pwee167's answer, however it is descriptive for each collection that you want to have included in your query.